# Why doesn't my NiFi Nar show up in the processor list?

Tags: apache-nifi

Just made my first NAR from a tutorial, put it in the /lib file and restarted NiFi.  The Processor shows up as loaded in the logs but does not show up in the processor list.  Any ideas?

Tutorial:  http://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-processor-json/

```
        @SideEffectFree
        @Tags({"JSON", "NIFI ROCKS"})
        @CapabilityDescription("Fetch value from json path.")
        public class JsonProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
           ...
        }
```

Edit:
I see two lines in the logs with this in it:

```
2017-07-06 19:34:06,200 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoaders Loaded NAR file: C:\UserApps\NIFI-1~1.0\.\work\nar\extensions\examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.nar-unpacked as class loader org.apache.nifi.nar.NarClassLoader[.\work\nar\extensions\examples-1.0-SNAPSHOT.nar-unpacked]
```

What should the processor be called in the list?  JsonProcessor?

Edit:

Tried changing the `<nifi.version>1.3.0</nifi.version>` in the pom from 1.2.0 to 1.3.0.  No joy.

Comment: Would probably need to see your code to check your NAR, or would need to see the full nifi-app.log to see if any errors occurred, or any statements saying the processor was skipped for some reason.

Comment: did you declared your processor as a `org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor` service? https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor

Comment: Is this something else that isn't in the tutorial above?  The tutorial says put it in the /lib file and restart.  Is there something else?  Where would I find that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So on top of coding up the program you must put a file called

```
org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor
```

in YOUR project to get it to show up.  I would suspect NiFi would scan for the classes with the annotations but alas, it does not.  Probably some security thing.

[image: NiFi processor program structure]

The tutorial above does have this in it.  "Browsing" got me again!

Answer (score 0):

I also used this tutorial to create a Customer Processor. The issue I had was that I mixed up the `./lib` directory.

When you start Apache Nifi, you would notice the following at the beginning of the log:

```
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
NiFi home: /usr/local/Cellar/nifi/1.6.0/libexec
```

Confirm that the NAR file is the `$NIFI_HOME/libexec/lib` folder which would be `/usr/local/Cellar/nifi/1.6.0/libexec/lib` in my case.

I hope this helps

*NB: I ran Apache Nifi on a Mac, logs might be different on another OS*